# can't save file in required location in C# metro app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, app.xaml

I'm developing a metro app that uses file input and output. The code I used to save the file is

```
StorageFolder appfolder = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("Appdata.abc", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync(DateFileName + ".uvraj", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Now how can I create/save my file inside the folder I created??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method on the `appfolder` object, instead of the `KnownFolder` you're using.

Like this:

```
StorageFolder appfolder = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("Appdata.abc", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
StorageFile file = await appfolder.CreateFileAsync(DateFileName + ".uvraj", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```